# How to fix constraint on a collection of case class in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Is there a way to have a constraint on a collection of case class.
In my case, I want to ensure that all elements in the collection have the same value for the first property.

Here is a sample of code to express what I mean

```
  case class In[T](values : Set[T])

  trait A
  case object A1 extends A
  case object A2 extends A

  case class Element(k: A, v: String)

  In(Set(Element(A1, "xxx"), Element(A1, "xxx"))) // should compile
  In(Set(Element(A1, "xxx"), Element(A2, "xxx"))) // should not compile
```

Comment: Have you tried with require(...)

Comment: Set have no order so... you should change to another type of collection like Seq!!!

Answer (score 4):

Is this acceptable solution for you?

```
case class In[T](values : Set[T])

trait A
case object A1 extends A
case object A2 extends A

case class Element[T <: A](k: T, v: String)

In(Set[Element[A1.type]](Element(A1, "xxx"), Element(A1, "xxx"))) // should compile
In(Set[Element[A1.type]](Element(A1, "xxx"), Element(A2, "xxx"))) // should not compile
```

Comment: I think this will work in the example because A2 doesn't extend A1 but taking A3 extends A2 then your code will compile (and I think is not what is expected).

Comment: not bad, but is doesn't enforce type constraint by design. It's still possible to instantiate an inconsistent `Set`.

Comment: I think it'll be hard to make general seq to enforce any type of constrains on objects it contains without telling the seq what exactly should be constrained. If you do not want to construct inconsistent set (inconsistent from your point of view, not from set's) perhaps user of the set ("In" class in our case) should check its consistensy somehow because set itself thinks it is consistent with any objects if you do not make it to enforce constrains explicitly.

Comment: I insist... is not Seq is Set (which has no order...)

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped ).